# File 'JDocumenterror' containing class 'JDocumenterror' not found

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I have integrated two applications,one developed using Joomla and other using php mvc.When submit a page in the second aplication it shows

> "File 'JDocumenterror' containing class 'JDocumenterror' not
>   found"

and does not redirect to the intended page.What can be done to remove this error?

Model:

```
    function addPolicy($post)
    {
        array_pop($post);

        //$this->printr($post);die();
        $policyBreakDown = $post['rtcPercentage']."_".$post['CecPercentage']."_".$post['partnerRTCPercentage']."_".$post['translationPercentage']."_".$post['otherRTCPercentage'];
        if($post['policy_for']<>'DL'){
            $getOtherPolicy = $this->getPolicyType($post['policy_for']);
            //print_r($getOtherPolicy);
            foreach($getOtherPolicy as $data){
                $othPolicyID[]=$data->policy_id;
            }
            if(count($othPolicyID)>0){
                //foreach($othPolicyID as $k=>$v){
                $ids = implode(",", $othPolicyID);
                $data = array("status=0");
                $this->updateSQL('tbl_policy', $data,
                    ' policy_id IN ('.$ids.')');

                //}
            }

        }


        $id = $this->insert('tbl_policy',array('title'=>$post['title'] , 'description'=>$post['description'] , 'status'=>'1','break_down'=>$policyBreakDown,'policy_for'=>$post['policy_for']));

        return $id; 
    }
```

Controller:

```
if(isset($_POST['AddPolicy']))
            {
                $id = $this->Model->addPolicy($_POST);
                $this->redirect('?policy&pg=policy_manage');
            }
```

Comment: It's hard to debug errors without seeing the code that caused them...

Comment: You will have to show how did you integrate these two. Then someone could help.